# jq | to return specific item in nested json object

Tags: jq

I am new to jq and cannot work out how to get idle value from the above json.  By using jq command to retrieve json.  How do I get idle value using jq?

```
{
  "sysstat": {
    "hosts": [
      {
        "nodename": "localhost.localdomain",
        "sysname": "Linux",
        "release": "4.13.13-200.fc26.x86_64",
        "machine": "x86_64",
        "number-of-cpus": 2,
        "date": "24/11/17",
        "statistics": [
          {
            "timestamp": "00:00:45",
            "cpu-load": [
              {
                "cpu": "0",
                "usr": 5.08,
                "nice": 0.03,
                "sys": 1.31,
                "iowait": 0.07,
                "irq": 0.73,
                "soft": 0.09,
                "steal": 0,
                "guest": 0,
                "gnice": 0,
                "idle": 92.69
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution, assuming the data is in `data.json`:

```
$ jq -M '.sysstat.hosts[0].statistics[0]."cpu-load"[0].idle' data.json
92.69
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/4Y2Ucl0I2C)

Comment: thanks for the help, the jqplay.org is good to play around with different command.  worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, a short-and-sweet solution is:

```
.. | .idle? // empty
```

If the location of "idle" is important, then in case it appears more than once (or not at all), you may wish to consider:

```
.sysstat.hosts[].statistics[] | .["cpu-load"][] | .idle
```

Comment: .. | .idle? does not really work for my case, but the one after do work.  thanks for help.

Comment: @chuongtrungvuong: I tested it with your example, and got the expected result. The jq version used is jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe With the .. operator you can address all attributes even if they are nested. .idle will then filter for you specific attribute. The question mark ignores errors and // empty replaces  non matching results (null) with empty, so nothing is shown in place of "null".